# What is a .backup format?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, format

Some time ago i was working on a database made in Postgresql, i learned to make backups by exporting the database to a .sql file, but i recently found a .backup file with the name of the database that i was working on at that time and i don't know how to restore the database from that file since Postgresql throw me an error when i try to restore the database. Anyone know anything about this format and how to restore anything in it?

Comment: Is it a binary format? What if you do `less mydb.backup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres does have a "custom" format produced by `pg_dump -Fc`. Try doing `pg_restore -l <filename>` and see if it lists the file's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Postgres backups are little more than large SQL scripts that are gzipped. You may want to see if you can "gzcat" the file and get any sanity out of it.